# Invoke Base Class Method in Generic Method C#

Tags: c#, generics

My Base Class is

```
public abstract class BaseContext {
    public void SaveChanges() {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And my Drived class is

```
public class DriveClass : BaseContext {    
}
```

I am having another class which contains generic methods to invoke Base class `SaveChanges` method like

```
public class AnyClass {  
    MyMethod<DriveClass>(repo);

    private void MyMethod<T>(T repo) {
        MethodInfo savech = typeof(T).GetMethod("SaveChanges", new Type[] {});
        savech.Invoke(repo, null);
    }
}
```

When I am trying

> GetMethod("SaveChanges", new Type[] {})

I am getting null, *which means that the methods in the BaseContext class can not be invoked.*

Please suggest any suggestions, how to invoke method from Abstract `BaseContext` Class.

Comment: Why isn't `MyMethod` non-generic with a `BaseContext` parameter? Then you can avoid reflection.

Comment: Hi vc, tried your suggestion, it is not working...giving error...please elaborate a bit more... thank you

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, because the T in your `MyMethod<T>` is not restricted to a BaseContext type, you cannot call the SaveChanges method directly.

If you need to use reflection to call some other method in a generic method, then you are not using generics correctly. Either use generics without reflection, or use reflection without generics.

This could be a solution:

```
public class AnyClass {
    private void MyMethod<T>(T repo) where T : BaseContext {
        repo.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Maarten, Existing solution is written in that way, I am trying to make minimum changes to the solution and achieve both. Please suggest solution where I can use both Generics and Reflection.

Comment: I added your suggestion and getting error : There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MyInterface' to 'BaseContext'

Comment: You didnt mention any MyInterface in your question. Besides that: what is your actual problem? Ignore generics and/or reflection, that is a solution, but first we need to know your problem.